# Hidden redirect in hacked site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

One of our Wordpress websites running on an Apache server was recently hacked via PHP injection.

The hackers installed hundreds of URLs that redirected to an external eCommerce that sold watches; the URLs were of the form `http://www.example.com/eta.php?some_file.html`; for example: `http://www.example.com/eta.php?Jewellery-Watches-Others-c138-4.html`.

We think we have deleted all infected PHP code. However, the hacked URLs, rather than returning 404, now do a 301 redirect to `http://www.example.com/?some_file.html` (that is, the same URL without the `eta.php` part), and finally show the website homepage, returning code 200. Please note that my `.htaccess` file seems to be perfectly clean.

**Where is this phantom redirect coming from?**

I would be very grateful to anybody that could help me understand what's going on. I am worried that we did not completely wiped out the hack.

Thank you for your attention!

**FURTHER DETAILS**

The file `eta.php` is nowhere to be found on the server. Replacing `eta.php` with a random file (ex. `ate.php`) in the hacked URLs yields a 404 code as expected.

In the end I managed to force the hacked URLs to return 404 using the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /eta\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Interestingly enough, this other rule did not work, as if the hack was somehow messing up with `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eta\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Nuke the server from orbit, reinstall from scratch, **tighten security this time around**, restore from know good backups (I hope you have some). There's usually little point in trying to clean something out; for all you know your server has been root-kitted and will constantly revert to a "hacked state" whatever you do.

Comment: You have probably some malicious code hidden somewhere that add this rewrite rule. Few steps to check: 1. look at the modification time on your WP installation files, and see if any file has been updated recently. 2. search for any add_rewrite_rule references and see if any looks suspicious. 3. look for any base64_decode references (hackers can hide malicious code using base64 strings)

Comment: Hacked site questions are off topic on SO; see https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Thank you @vard! Following your advice, I have found three entries in the database that were responsible for the redirect: `_redirect_rule_from: /eta.php*`, `_redirect_rule_to: /`, `_redirect_rule_status_code: 301`. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it. By the way, this makes the advice of @deceze even more valuable. I am on a shared server as a reseller (WHM + cPanel), so nuking it is out of the question :-) But I will delete & recreate the website account as soon as possible. Thanks guys, you're great!

Answer (score 1):

One good thing is to you backup MySQL database and open in notepad. Find all links and delete. After that save .sql file and upload back to see.

Also look where is inserted javascript/iframe inside your HTML file via source code and find if exist in database and delete.

Also reinstall wordpress instalation, reinstall plugins and template (replace all files with new files).

That is way how I save many sites.

Also can do things what @vard write inyour comment.

Comment: Thank you Ivijan, that's plenty of useful advices! In the end, it turns out that the malicious redirect I have asked about is due to a hidden `__redirect_rule` directive in the database, very similar to the one @vard suggested to look for. Thank you anyway for your answer, which I will definitely follow the next time one of our websites is hacked :-)

Comment: My pleasure is to help others. Web development are huge area and you can't know everything. Is not possible. Becouse of that you need to learn, get expirience to solve this kind of issues or someone ask to help you. Stupid questions not exists. All the best!